# Selecting a line segment with an azimuth value closest to the azimuth value of another line segment in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, query, select-by-location, azimuth

I have a road network dataset and a dataset that consists of multiple disconnected lines of varying lengths in QGIS.

[image]

Most of these lines are (largely) parallel to the road network, but their shape and distance between these lines and the road network can differ. Since these lines tell something about the condition of the road segments, I would like to select/extract the road segments that are parallel to these lines. So far, I have calculated the line bearing/azimuth of each road- and line segment and added this to a new column to both attributes tables. I now need to select the road with azimuth closest to the azimuth of the disconnected line (let’s say within a percentage difference of 5 or 10%).

Any thoughts on how to do this in QGIS?

Comment: Don't, that's bound to fail; similar angles can occur all over the place. If your whole dataset looks like in the picture, you might get good results with finding the spatial nearest neighbor of the centroid of your lines to the network segments.

Comment: I understand, therefore I should create a buffer first to only look for neighbouring line segments. However, I am not sure how to incorporate these two criteria in my analysis